# Upload file using firemonkey

Tags: delphi, file-upload, webserver, firemonkey

Is it possible, to upload a file to a HTTP webserver in a firemonkey delphi application? If yes, how? I've searched a lot, but I haven't found anything useful. Firemonkey is not really popular yet, so there is not enough source about the topic.

Comment: Yes, it's entirely possible. The Indy components work in FMX applications on most (if not all) platforms, so any question asking how to upload a file in Delphi using any supported protocol via Indy would apply. Your question as stated here is far too vague to suggest which Indy component you should use - what exactly does "upload a file to a webserver" mean? Via HTTP? FTP? Something else? What platform? Windows? iOS? OS X? Android?

Comment: I would like to upload using HTTP. The platform of my application is Android and IOS

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to include that information, instead of burying it in the comments where people can't see it. Also, please keep in mind when you ask future questions here that you need to be **specific** about what you're asking, or it makes it difficult for people to answer your questions. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for file uploads to a web server (HTTP) you can use the Indy TIdHTTP component.

Internet Direct (Indy) 10.6 supports all Delphi target platforms.

Uploading usually is done with a HTTP POST request. There are many example for POST with TIdHTTP, and examples how to configure TIdHTTP for standard HTTP and HTTPS (TLS) servers on Stack Overflow.